# Interpolation in Angular innerHtml

Tags: typescript, angular8

I have some HTML templates with interpolation and ng classes are stored in the database. When fetched and used in `innerHtml`, everything is working except Angular's interpolation, ng classes and ng `for`.

I tried `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` and tried lots of things found in Google.

Does anybody know any solution?

Comment: can you post a sample html template with interpolation and ng classes

Comment: Show us some code you've tried.